# Pass parameters to script using Start-DSCConfiguration

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc

I have a DSC configuration that looks like this

```
configuration DBServer
{
  param(
    [PSCredential]$SqlAdminCredential
  )

  node "localhost"
  {
    Script ConfigureSSRS {
      SetScript = {
        & sqlcmd -S $RSConnection -i $DBCreateFile -U $SQLAdminCredential.UserName -P $SQLAdminCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

I'm running it on azure VMs using a JSON template deployment with a DSC extension containing this `Properties` node:

```
"Properties": {
    "SqlAdminCredential": {
        "userName": "PrivateSettingsRef:SQLAdmin",
        "password": "PrivateSettingsRef:SQLAdminPass"
    },
```

Those two value are indeed defined in the `protectedSettings` node:

```
"SQLAdmin": "[parameters('sqlAuthenticationLogin')]",
"SQLAdminPass": "[parameters('sqlAuthenticationPassword')]"
```

But I keep getting null reference exceptions in the code I listed above whenever I try to use the credentials. I've tried `$using:SqlAdminCredential` and I believe yesterday I tried `$global:SqlAdminCredential` as well.

I'm currently attempting to troubleshoot this but I don't like making a change to my configuration and then spending 15 minutes waiting for a deploy to see if it worked. However, I can't figure out how to pass this credential object parameter using `Start-DscConfiguration` in order to troubleshoot it on an existing VM. How can I do this?

Bonus points if you can fix my actual problem and tell me how to access `$SqlAdimCredential` from inside `ConfigureSSRS.SetScript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment, I have decided to be poorly behaved and do this:

```
configuration DBServer
{
  param(
    [PSCredential]$SqlAdminCredential
  )

  node "localhost"
  {
    $adminCreds = $SqlAdminCredential #a hack

    Script ConfigureSSRS {
      SetScript = {
        $SqlAdminCredential = $using:adminCreds
```

I will wait for a better solution but this appears to be working.

Comment: When you do this the credentials are serialized to the mof without being encrypted first

Comment: @aboersch Isn't the MOF compiled before executing and receiving any parameters?

Comment: You can use this, however only if you are compiling and applying the configuration to the same machine. If you use a $using: it is serialized and encrypted with the local machine's certificate. It is therefore not suitable for pull server or other scenarios where you author on one system and then deploy to another.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

1. Use the PSDSCRunAsCredential of the Script Resource if you need the entire script to run under a single user.
2. Create your own DSC Resource that uses PSCredential Parameters.

Comment: I actually don't want any portion of the script to run under that user as it is not a windows user. I just want those credentials accessible to sqlcmd. In my uneducated opinion, a custom resource might be too much overhead for as simple a problem as this one.

Comment: Creating a module is a piece of cake

Here is a gist I created with a simple resource that displays a credential's password in verbose mode: 

1. Create a folder named after your module in C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\
2. Run New-ModuleManifest -Path C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\<Your Module Name>\<Your Module Name>.psd1 and provide the other arguments
3. Write a class based Resource https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/authoringresourceclass

Comment: Actually, I've already got a custom one in this solution :) It just seems like a lot of extra code when my (admittedly silly) workaround is doing ok.

Comment: Here is a gist I created with a simple resource that displays a credential's password in verbose mode: https://gist.github.com/aboersch/65e846a4966fe2c4708ed21d655a54a7